# Vue Computed property based on plugin value

Tags: vue.js, plugins, reactive, computed-properties

I'm actually in the process of refactoring a vue app by integrating it a plugin but but i face a problem concerning computed data.

What I'm trying to do is to target the data that as be modified in the plugin by a computed property, but the problem is that vue don't target the change of the data

Here is a very simple example of my problem

**The plugin**

```
install(Vue) {
  Vue.prototype.$myPlugin= {
    data: 0,

    setValue(val) {
      this.data = val
    }
  }
}
```

**The component** (dont't log despite the modification of the value)

```
computed: {
  reactiveData() {
    return this.$myPlugin.data1
  }
},
watch: {
  reactiveData() {
    console.log('Value changed')
  }
},
mounted() {
  this.$myPlugin.setValue(32)
  this.$myPlugin.setValue(64)
}
```

I know that some vue data for a certain reason aren't reactive but I really need to understand how I could make my plugin reactive.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly make the data reactive using [Vue.observable](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-observable):

```js
Vue.prototype.$myPlugin = Vue.observable({
  data: 0,

  setValue(val) {
    this.data = val
  }
})
```

Comment: Oh Thanks man ! it works !
Now I know the trick haha